# notifying the user about successful update in codeigniter

Tags: php, activerecord, codeigniter, error-handling

i'm using these two lines to update my table using codeigninter active records

```
$this->db->where('reference_number', $reference);
$this->db->update('patient', $data);
```

what i want to de is to check weather it successfully updates the table and according to that i want to give a notification to the user, how can i check the successful update is happened with this lines? there is a no clue in the user guide telling that by putting the line

```
if($this->db->update('patient', $data));
```

will give us a true or false value, can we do like that? or is there any other solution to this problem?

regards,
Rangana

Comment: Here is an answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030642/check-if-db-update-successful-with-codeigniter-when-potentially-no-rows-are-upd

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can put a code like this in your model...

```
function func() {
    $this->db->where('reference_number', $reference);
    $this->db->update('patient', $data); 

    $report = array();
    $report['error'] = $this->db->_error_number();
    $report['message'] = $this->db->_error_message();
    return $report;
}
```

_error_number and _error_message use the [mysql_errno](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php) and [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) functions of php.

Then inside your controller, you can check for the error like this...

```
$this->load->model("Model_name");
$report = $this->Model_name->func();
if (!$report['error']) {
  // update successful
} else {
  // update failed
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition, you can also use `$this->db->affected_rows()` to check if something was actually updated.

Comment: thank you very much Bogdan for this additional detail, i will implement that also! :)

Answer (score 2):

Can I just follow on from @ShiVik - if you use the `_error_number()` or `_error_message()` functions, you will need to disable automatic database error reporting.

You can do this in `/config/database.php`. Set `db_debug = FALSE`.

The way I handle this functionality in my system is just to test the result returned by the ActiveRecord class using something like

```
if($this->db->update('patient', $data) === TRUE) {   
  $flash_data = array('type' => 'success', 'message'
=> 'Update successful!');
$this->session->set_flashdata('flash', $flash_data);
}
```

Although usage of the flash session data system is up to you :) You'd need to add in the relevant front-end to this in your view files, and tweak to your liking etc.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
return ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```