# How to know affected rows using DB Transaction?

Tags: database, codeigniter, transactions, rows-affected

```
$this->db->trans_start();
        $obj = array(
                'id_supplier'=>$idsupplier,
                'nama_cp'=>$namacp,
                'email'=>$email,
                'note'=>$note
        );
        $this->supplier_model->updateSupplier($obj);

        $this->supplier_bahan_baku_model->deleteSupplierBahanBakuByIdSupplier($idsupplier);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($bb); $i++) 
        {
            $obj2 = array(
                'id_supplier'=>$idsupplier,
                'id_bb'=>$bb[$i]
            );
            //print_r($obj2);
            $this->supplier_bahan_baku_model->insertSupplierBahanBaku($obj2);
        }

        $this->db->trans_complete();    
        if($this->db->trans_status() === TRUE)
        {
            if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
            {
                echo 1;
            }
            else
            {
                echo 0;
            }
        }
```

I need to know the affected rows for some reason..
And I need to use db transaction because there are many query..
Please help me..
Thank You ^^

Comment: What error are you getting or does your transaction status always return false?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if db->update successful with Codeigniter when potentially no rows are updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030642/check-if-db-update-successful-with-codeigniter-when-potentially-no-rows-are-upd)

Comment: First check yourself and then ask here.

Comment: @MayankVadiya not exactly a duplicate, but the 2nd and 5th answers do explain how to use affected_rows.

Comment: @nikhil_gandhi The transaction status works. But the affected rows always return false, but when i see it in my sql database it works fine

Comment: Ok. In the else part try to log the error and than revert me what you are getting.

Comment: @nikhil_gandhi  try this: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); But I cant see any error

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this.

```
$this->db->affected_rows();
```

It will return the affected rows, or will return 0 if no rows were effected.